# Validating iOS screen for user errors

Tags: ios, web-services, core-data, crash

I have developed an iOS enterprise app for iPad. When it is launched it connects to a webservice, gets some data, and stores it in Core Data. Then the next screens use this data and do what is needed, like fill `UITextFields`, `drop downs`, show the user a `UIAlertView`, etc. Basically i use the data, manipulate it, and save it.

Consider this: I install the app now in morning, I use it immediately, and then I click the home button on iPad and leave it there for couple of hours. I then launch the app, and it shows a black screen before crashing and going back to iPad main menu.

Why is it crashing like that? Any ideas?

If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: What does your debug console say?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your logs for errors.

Plug your device to your computer and open Xcode/Organizer/Devices/Device Logs

Comment: Thanks. I did that and it has lot of information. But  i can get the crash logs if i have the device with me. What if the user is having an iPad and suppose the app crashes on his iPad then how will i get his crash log.

Comment: You can check them on iTunes Connect, under your app details there is a menu called Crash Reports.

Comment: This is weird..i am trying to login into iTunes connect and it says no username blah@bla.com exists..i login into developer member center just fine. Just off the phone with Apple Dev help. They said iTunes Connect is not available to Enterprise Developer program members because we are not submitting apps to the App Store.

Comment: You can make a new version of your app bundled with a crash reporting tool. You can try the open-source PLCrashReporter.